# how to check the value of a cookie in varnish

Tags: varnish, cookies

I have a cookie for language. I want to check if this cookie is set and to check its value to redirect the user to specific page.
the cookie name is **Lang** and its value might be **En,Fr,or Ar**

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "Lang"){
//now i want to check for the cookie value
//if LANG=="Ar"
// set req.url =  req.url "CookieValue"
}
```

anybody know how to check for cookie value in varnish??
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since all the cookies - both name and value - are in the `req.http.Cookie` string, you should be able to check for both name and value at the same time. Unfortunately, Varnish does not have any specialized methods for dealing with cookies - you must use regular expressions.

It is important to note that cookies are delimited by a semicolon and white space, for example:

```
cookie1=abc; cookie2=def
```

We know, therefore that our cookie is either at the start of req.http.Cookie, or is preceded by a semicolon and white space, and either ends with a semicolon, or is at the end of req.http.Cookie. Given this, we can construct a regex that will match our cookie and the semicolon, if any. Something like:

```
(^|;\s*)(Lang=En)(;|$)
```

Briefly, going through the above we have:

- First set of brackets - match the start:

  - `^` means start of string
  - `|` means OR
  - `;` is taken literally (i.e. semicolon)
  - `\s` means white space
  - `*` means one or more repetitions of the preceding character
  - *Summary:* either the start of the string or a semicolon followed by white space
- Second set of brackets - match the cookie:

  - `Lang` is the name of the cookie
  - `En` is the value of the cookie
- Third set of brackets - match the end

  - `;` is taken literally (i.e. semicolon)
  - `|` means OR
  - `$` means end of string
  - *Summary:* either a semicolon or the end of the string

Using the above, we can check for the cookies and perform some action on them:

```
if (req.http.Cookie ~ "(^|;\s*)(Lang=En)(;|$)"){
    //do something with En
} elseif (req.http.Cookie ~ "(^|;\s*)(Lang=Fr)(;|$)") {
    //do something with Fr;
}
```

There may be better ways, or more efficient regexes (unfortunately, varnish doesn't have user defined variables - which means you can't use regex capture groups) - but hopefully this will do the job.

Arguably, you could construct a regex with a capture group using regsub, and set that as a subdomain, perhaps something like:

```
set req.url = regsub(req.http.Cookie, "(?:^|;\s*)(?:Lang=(.*?))(?:;|$)", "\1.")+"example.com";
```

In the case of 'Lang=en', you would capture the 'en' add a period (.) and prepend to 'example.com' giving you en.example.com. I'd suggest though directly using a cookie to set the URL - without a lot of error checking - would be a very bad solution. If you just have 3 languages, a couple of if statements and a default would be much safer.

Note: the above is untested, and regexes aren't my forte - expect a few mistakes - but hopefully the premise works.

Comment: in [sub vcl_recv] i have added this line
[set req.url = req.url  "/en";]
is it supposed change my request url from http://example.com to http://example.com/en ???Thanks for your help

Comment: a) Firstly you need a 'normalized' req.url (i.e. how do you know the url isn't currently example.com/page.php - adding /en to the end of that wouldn't be good - you could use a regex to do the replacement, but that should be asked as a different question. b) you need a plus sign (+) for concatenation in Varnish. c) changing req.url will only 'internally' change the path (i.e. a rewrite) it will not send a 301 (or 302) redirect to the client.